# Unhandled Exception: Bad state: cannot get a field on a DocumentSnapshotPlatform which does

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

[image]
I want to display the current user name on my app.

I tried this but got the error

> Unhandled Exception: Bad state: cannot get a field on a DocumentSnapshotPlatform which does not exist

```
Future getUserData() async {
    User? user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    final DocumentSnapshot doc = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("UserData")
        .doc(user!.uid)
        .get();

    name = doc['name'];
    print("name $name");
  }
```

Then, I tried this:

```
  Future getUserData() async {
    User? user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    try {
      final doc = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("UserData")
          .doc(user!.uid)
          .get();

      final ds = await doc.get();
      final data = ds.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;

      name = data['name'];
      print("name $name");
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
```

But it shows an error for the doc.get()

> 1 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found.
> Try adding the missing arguments

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

.get method expect a key('String') of filed/filePath.

```dart
  final doc = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("UserData")
      .doc(user!.uid)
      .get();

  final name = await doc.get("name");
  print("name $name");
```

Also make sure the project setup is ok. More about [reading data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data).